# Runtime TypeError: hmrClient.send is not a function

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

After upgrade of RN from `0.59.10` to `0.61.4` I get:

> TypeError: hmrClient.send is not a function

when trying to start the app. Just pressing on dismiss seems to work.

Other people suggest removing `metro` and `metro-core` and setting

setting `metro-react-native-babel-preset` to `0.56` but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Issue was reported here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26958

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was related to an old `metro-config` module.

I had an old version of `"react-native-fs": "2.13.3"`. This had a dependency on `metro-config@0.48.3`.

I updated react-native-fs  to `2.16.2` (`2.16.x` is recommended for RN `0.60+`) and the error disappeared.

Also I made sure in package.json I have: `"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.0"`.

Sources:

I got the `metro-config` hint from **huntie**'s answer from here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26958#issuecomment-558653561

Note: if you have an old dependency that cannot be updated adding:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "metro-config": "0.56.3"
  },
```

in the package.json could also fix the issue.

Comment: In my case, upgrading metro-react-native-babel-present to 0.56.0 was not sufficient, but when I upgraded metro to that version, the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error displaying every time I ran/refreshed the app and fast refresh was not working for me. I have a react native (0.63.3) app with an init without expo.

This worked for me:

```
yarn add metro@0.56.0
```

from: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/react-native-community/releases/140/530142204